# Loopback rest connector remote with multiple method not working

Tags: node.js, strapi, loopback4

I'm using Loopback4 as an Central API. I'm trying to call a method of the 3rd party API through a remote method in Loopback. I'm using Strapi as 3rd party API and communicate this to loopback4

With Loopback, I have a datasource which looks like the following:

```
const strapiConfig = {
  name: 'strapi',
  connector: 'rest',
  baseURL: appConfig.strapi.host,
  crud: false,
  options: {
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Authorization" : `Bearer ${appConfig.strapi.token}`
    }
  },
  operations: [
    {
      "template": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": `${strapiUrl}/pages/{pageId}`
      },
      "functions": {
        "getOnePage": ["pageId"]
      }
    },
    {
      "template": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": `${strapiUrl}/pages`
      },
      "functions": {
        "getPages": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "template": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": `${strapiUrl}/glossary/{id}`
      },
      "functions": {
        "getOneGlossary": ['id']
      }
    },
    {
      "template": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": `${strapiUrl}/glossary`
      },
      "functions": {
        "getGlossary": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "template": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": `${strapiUrl}/faq`
      },
      "functions": {
        "getFaqs": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "template": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": `${strapiUrl}/faq/{id}`
      },
      "functions": {
        "getOneFaq": ['id']
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

the only endpoint that are working is the pages

Any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error/status code do you get when calling the other Endpoints?

Have you set the Roles & Permissions within Strapi?
Example (depending on the Strapi version):

1. Navigate to SETTINGS - Users & Permissions Plugin.
2. Click the Public Role.
3. Scroll down under Permissions, open the Application tab and find the collection type you want to edit.
4. i.e. Click the checkbox next to find and findone.
5. Click Save

Check: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html#_7-set-roles-and-permissions

Comment: I solved it..  It was my own mistake. My config url should match on the endpoint from strapi endpoints. in my config above im trying match that to my current loopback endpoint. so its now fixed. Thank you